# ¿Cómo obtengo la hora actual en base a la zona horaria?

Tags: android-studio, datetime, kotlin

Así estoy obteniendo y formateando la hora actual:

```
    var c = Calendar.getInstance()
    var timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.US)
    var time = timeFormat.format(c.time)
```

Necesito obtener la hora de "America/Mazatlan"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Android 8.0 puedes usar `ZoneId.of(...)` para definir la zona horaria, y de esta forma determinar la hora (o fecha) actual:

```
    ZoneId fromTimeZone = ZoneId.of("America/Mazatlan");    //Zona horaria
    LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now();          //fecha actual
    ZonedDateTime currentTime = today.atZone(fromTimeZone);

    String DATE_FORMAT = "hh:mm:ss a z";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT);

    System.out.println("Hora Actual: " + formatter.format(currentTime));
```